# Issue matching non-nested for statements with Clang ASTMatcher

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to match single for loops in C++ code using Clang ASTMatcher's, i.e. in a source file as below

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++){ } 
for(int y=0;y<10;y++){for(int z=0;z<5;z++){}}
```

I want to match only '`for(int x=0;x<10<x++){ }`'

To accomplish this I have built a matcher:

```
StatementMatcher forStmtMatcher = forStmt(unless(anyOf(hasAncestor(forStmt()),hasDescendant(forStmt()))))
```

which I believe should work, but it doesn't. The matches include `for(int y=0;y<10;y++)` which I do not want and if I swap the position of the conditions in the anyOf() matcher, it matches `for(int z=0;z<5;z++)` instead which I also do not want.

Can anybody explain why or tell me how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that what you've posted looks like it should work - but it fails to produce the expected result with both clang-query 3.8 and 4.0. If you try binding the variables of the intermediate matches it seems to work.

Clang query code (type-set for clarity, remove the linebreaks to run)

```
set bind-root false
match forStmt(
    unless(hasAncestor(forStmt().bind('x'))),      
    unless(hasDescendant(forStmt().bind('y')))).bind('for')
```

For an equivalent example:

```
int main()
{ 
    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){ }
    for(int y=0;y<10;y++){for(int z=0;z<5;z++){}}
}
```

Produces:

```
Match #1:

/vagrant/stackoverflow-ast-query/loops.cpp:3:5: note: "for" binds here
    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){ }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.
```

Looks like it's a possible bug in the AST matcher constructor conversions.

Comment: Yes you are right, strangely enough `StatementMatcher forStmtMatcher = forStmt(unless(hasAncestor(forStmt())), unless(hasDescendant(forStmt())))` does not work either but when I bind something in-between e.g. `StatementMatcher forStmtMatcher = forStmt(unless(hasAncestor(forStmt())), hasLoopInit(declStmt(hasSingleDecl(varDecl().bind("init")))) ,unless(hasDescendant(forStmt())))` it works as I would like. There must be some bug there